# After page loaded, reload page once after 2 second delay

Tags: javascript

This works `setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 2000);`

But it loops.

How to do it once?

Comment: Some options include: Set a cookie. Set something in the local storage. Append a query string to the URL. Append an anchor to the URL.

Comment: there is one way where you will have to keep track for the reloads of the page that means a condition to check the number of times the page loaded which will be stored in the browser storage.

Comment: You can store a cookie when the first time you reload. Your `if` case should look for the cookie. If it exists relaod and then before reloading remove cookie so that it can be repeated again.

You would want to look for GDPR before you use cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this?

```
if(!localStorage["reloaded"]) {

    localStorage["reloaded"] = "1"

    setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 2000);
}
```

You could use a cookie or query string as well.